# HTTP::Request error with query string

Tags: perl

I'm having an error with HTTP::Request in perl, where it wont post with the quesry string as shown bellow:

```
$request = HTTP::Request->new(POST => "http://example.com/file.pl?query=blablabla");

 $ua = LWP::UserAgent->new;
 $response = $ua->request($request);
```

It's not sending the post with "?query=blablabla" rather only sending the post to "http://example.com/file.pl" instead of http://example.com/file.pl?query=blablabla

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work.

```
$param = "query=blablabla";
$req = HTTP::Request->new(POST => $url);
$req->content($param);

$ua = LWP::UserAgent->new;
$res = $ua->request($req);
```

Also you can add headers to your request like this:

```
$req->header('Accept-Encoding' => "gzip,deflate");
$req->header('Accept-Charset' => "ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.7");
```

Comment: Ah, thanks, How would I do this if I were to use multiple query strings like : http://example.com/test.pl?query=qweqw&two=rue&three=6454

Comment: that case $param = "query=qweq&two=rue&three=6454";